# Electromagnetic field produced by a charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I guess vibration of a charge particle produces vibrating EM wave and oscillation of a charged particle will produce oscillating EM wave. If charge is only accelerating (speeding up) what will happen then ? I guess amplitude of the EM wave produced by it will also be increasing and increasing until charge starts to deaccelerate. Am i right ?

Now when the charge is vibrating the electromagnetic wave produced by it will not have fixed frequency but EM wave produced by oscillating charge will have fixed frequency ?

And in third case when charge is just accelerating (speeding up) the EM wave we get will be the combination of probably many sine waves probably having different  frequencies (Fourier series).

Is everything right ?

Comment: What is the difference between vibrating particle and oscillating particle?

Comment: "In oscillation time taken to complete one cycle is constant, in vibration it may not be."